# Speech Recognition using K means

Tags: python, speech-recognition, k-means, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am referring to following code :
https://github.com/Z3376/Speech-Recognition-with-Transfer-Learning/blob/master/audio_task2.ipynb

I have built CNN model for feature extraction and want to perform clustering using K means.
I have used one .wav file(conversation between call centre agent and customer) to test my model and want to perform speaker recognition on it.

```
kmeans = KMeans(3,init='k-means++')
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(features)

unique,counts = np.unique(y_kmeans,return_counts=True)
print(unique)
print(counts)
```

It is giving me output:
       [0 1 2]
         [33 32 74]

What does [33 32 74] signify?
How I get to know about the speakers ?
Please also tell the best way to check accuracy

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `np.unique()` to see the output from that function, then compared that to the output you're printing?

Comment: `np.unique()` outputs the unique values and in the above case it outputs the unique data points corresponding to a cluster. But how this is used in speech recognition process, is still ambiguous to me.

Comment: You have the unique values (cluster labels) and the counts (samples belonging to each cluster). As for what that means for your specific problem, there's really not enough info about your task or process in your question to be able to tell you with any specificity

Comment: If you open the github link that I have shared, you are able to see {0: 291, 1: 296, 2: 371, 3: 15, 4: 427, 5: 343} as output of K means clustering.I got an idea that there are 6 clusters :0-5 and 291,296 etc represent the data points in cluster. But how can i recognize speakers using above output.

Comment: On this site, we ask that you provide the full description of the task in the text of your question, not as an external link. The question "how can I recognize speakers" is far too broad for this site, and is dependent on the intent of the tutorial you are following. Based on the link, it says "...K-means to estimate the number of speakers and duration of speech..." so that appears to tell you the number of speakers and the sum of time each person spent speaking.